# phoenix lambda and argument dereferencing

Tags: c++, boost-phoenix

Can somebody show me how to implement an equivalent of the following using boost::phoenix lambda?
I know I could implement it in many other ways but I'm trying to learn the Phoenix lambda expressions and so far all my attempts in this example failed.

What I want to do is to use the std::remove_if to iterate through my set of weak_ptrs and remove the expired ones.

So the code would look something like:

```
typedef std::set<weak_ptr<Xyz>> XyzWptrSetType;
...
XyzWptrSetType   xyzWptrSet;
...
XyzWptrSetType::iterator it =
    std::remove_if(xyzWptrSet.begin(), xyzWptrSet.end(),
                   (boost::phoenix::arg_names::_1->expied()));  
// the lambda part DOESN'T compile in previous line
std::erase(it, xyzWptrSet.end());
```

Most of the lambda examples I've found are very simplistic and do not deal with calling a member function on a lambda argument object especially when there is more than one level of indirection. I.e. the _1 is expected to represent the set's iterator which by dereferencing with "->" returns value_type (being weak_ptr), on which I want to call expired. But since _1 is in fact **not** dirrectly an iterator but rather an "phoenix::actor", my dereferencing doesn't compile.

Thanks for all the creative inputs in advance.

Gabe

Comment: Finally I found one quite similar example and made the following change which compiles.
If it's incorrect can someone please correct this?

    using boost::phoenix::arg_names::_1;
    XyzWptrSetType::iterator it =
         std::remove_if(xyzWptrSet.begin(), xyzWptrSet.end(),
                       (&_1->*&weak_ptr<Xyz>::expired)()));  

Haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost phoenix (and boost lambda) do not support the -> operator.  You can use the "pointer to member" operator (->*) as a reasonable alternative.

I find it useful to define the member pointer as a separate variable immediately before the line that uses a lambda expression:

```
bool (weak_ptr<Xyz>::*expired)()const = &weak_ptr<Xyz>::expired ;
XyzWptrSetType::iterator it =
    std::remove_if(xyzWptrSet.begin(), xyzWptrSet.end(), (&_1->*expired)() );
```

As others have noted, it is also worth considering bind() for situations like yours.

Answer (score 5):

Boost.Phoenix, and Boost.Lambda before it, excel at certain tasks, but not at others. One of those others that it doesn't really work at is anything to do with directly calling a function by name.

Boost.Phoenix lambdas can be quickly and easily created for overloaded operators. But if you need a function name, then you have to use ugly syntax:

```
boost::phoenix::bind(&boost::weak_ptr::expired, boost::phoenix::arg_names::_1)
```

That is what your lambda looks like. You can use some `using` directives to clip off namespaces, but that's ultimately what it's going to look like. It's really no different from using `boost::bind` at this point:

```
boost::bind(&boost::weak_ptr::expired, _1)
```

Boost.Phoenix, and Boost.Lambda before it, are best used for lambda expressions that use overloaded operators, or explicitly-defined Phoenix action objects. If you just have a plain old function or member function, you have to bind it to call it. So you may as well just use `boost::bind`.